# Complex OrderBy in Linq

Tags: linq, sql-order-by

I have an list of DemoInfo object with list of StatInfo object in it as below-:

```
public class DemoInfo
{
  public string name;
  public List<StatInfo> stat;
  public string workLocation;
}
```

Further StatInfo is below object

```
public class StatInfo
{
  public string contact;
  public DateTime createdDate;
  public string action;
}
```

I need to orderby list of DemoInfo by createdDate

How can I do that in Linq?

Comment: Why sql-order-by tag?

Comment: Since `stat` is a list, which `createdDate` do you want to use for the ordering?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is because you haven't got a proper specification

> I need to orderby list of DemoInfo by createdDate

You can't do that, becuase a `DemoInfo` has no `CreatedDate`. If you assume that a `DemoInfo` was created the day that it got its first `StatInfo` then you could use the oldest `StatInfo` to order:

> I need to order my sequence of `DemoInfo` in ascending order by its creation date, which is defined as the date of its oldest `StatInfo`.

This still has a problem: what is the `CreatedDate` of a `DemoInfo` after all its `StatInfos` are removed? And removing the oldest `StatInfo` of a `DemoInfo` with many `StatInfos` suddenly changes the `CreatedDate` of the `DemoInfo`.

But let's assume that that's no problem for you, and you want all `DemoInfo` without any `StatInfo` last in your result (because they will get their `CreationDate` in future, when it gets its first `StatInfo`. Your query will be like:

```
var result = myDemoInfos.Select(demoInfo => new
    {
        DemoInfo = demoInfo,
        // if the demoInfo has a non-null stat and a non-empty stat
        // order it by ascending StatInfo.CreatedDate, and take the first
        // otherwise use DateTime.MaxValue (Created in far future)
        CreationDate = ( (demoInfo.stat != null) && (demoInfo.stat.Any()) ?
            demoInfo.Stat
                .Select(statInfo => createdDate)
                .OrderBy(createdDate => createdDate)
                .First() :             // you know there is a first, you just checked Any()
                DateTime.MaxValue,     // if there is no First, take far future
    })
    .OrderBy(item => item.CreationDate)
    .Select(item => item.DemoInfo);
```

This can be smarter: you don't have to sort all createdDates, you only need the createdDate with the smallest TickCount:

```
TickCount = ( (demoInfo.stat != null) && (demoInfo.stat.Any()) ?
     demoInfo.stat.Select(statInfo => statInfo.createdDate.TickCount).Min() :
     DateTime.MaxValue.TickCount,
```

And sort by ascending TickCount